# How do i call this Applet in this program?

Tags: java, swing, applet, joptionpane, javasound

I am using `JOptionPane` to make a menu that calls and executes program separately (the applet and menu are not required, i'm just doing it to make it better). I tried to call the `init()` method but it says "**non-static method init() cannot be referenced from a static statement."** The applet is used to play a song

Code:

**First Program:**
*

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   public class MexicoProject
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        String[] choice = {"History", "Trivia", "Intro", "Anthem", "Quit"};
        String Menu;
  do
        {
            Menu = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome, this program will teach you about the history of Mexico.\nPick one of the options below.",
                "Mexico History", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choice, choice[0]);

            if (Menu == null)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pick something!");
            else
            {
                switch (Menu)
                {
                    case "History":
                        MexicoHistory.History();
                        break;
                    case "Trivia":
                        Quiz();
                        break;
                    case "Intro":
                        FrenchIntro.Intro();
                        break;
                    case "Anthem":
                        MexicoAnthem.Init();
                        break;
                    case "Quit":
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong!  Try again!");
                }
            }   
        } while (Menu != "Quit");

    }
    public static void History()
    {
    }
    public static void Quiz()
    {
    }
}*
```

**Second Program:**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MexicoAnthem extends Applet
  { 
    Button button;

      public void Init()
      {
              BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
              setLayout(layout);
              Font font = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 32);
              setFont(font);
              button = new Button("Play Sound");
              add("Center", button);
              resize(250, 250);
      }

      public boolean action(Event evt, Object arg)
      {
              if (evt.target instanceof Button)
              {
                    URL codeBase = getCodeBase();
                    play(codeBase, "MexicanNationalAnthem.wav");
               }
      return true;
      }
}
```

Comment: "call this applet in this program".... Do you really think people will get anything meaningful from your title?

Comment: what does your title mean?  Please give a meaningful title which give a meaningful summary of your problem, e.g. How to embed an applet in a Swing application; or; Meaning of "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static statement", etc

Comment: sorry. do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: There is already a very sensible answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call an instance method on a class -- don't do that but instead call it on an instance -- create an object from the class and then call the method.

e.g.,

It's not:

```
MyClass.someMethod();
```

but rather

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.someMethod();
```

---

And regardless, this is not how you use applets. Rather they're supposed to be used in an HTML page or with an applet loader. Instead create a JFrame or JDialog and display it.

Comment: How would i use a jframe for it

Answer (score 0):

> How do i call this Applet in this program?

Well, don't do that.

All it does is include a button to play a clip.

A `Clip` can be played as seen in the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Use a `JButton` for the button, and add the `ActionListener` as seen in [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

---

As an aside.  That `Applet` based code is so old it is using methods deprecated long ago:

```
I:\projects\numbered\all\AllClasses\src\MexicoAnthem.java:30: warning: 
  [deprecation] action(Event,Object) in Component has been deprecated
      public boolean action(Event evt, Object arg)
```

The Java Docs go on to mention:

> As of JDK **version 1.1,** should register this component as `ActionListener` on component which fires action events.

***Do not base code on it.***